# How to decide between Global or Local vector for m choose n

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we want to write a code that prints all ways of selecting n out of m options.
I think, the programming language does not matter, but if I should state it, Python.
I put the assignments in a vector A. Do I better define A as a global variable or pass it to the function each time? Why?

```
def choose(ind, n):
  if n == 0:
    print(A)
    return

  elif len(A)<= ind:
      return
  else:

    A[ind] = 1 
    choose(ind + 1, n - 1)

    A[ind] = 0 
    choose(ind + 1, n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Always*** prefer passing over mutating globals whenever feasible.

Say you have the following functions:

```
def some_fun1 (n):
    return n + 1;

m = 1;  
def some_fun2 ():
    return m + 1
```

With the first function, you can load up your REPL and throw data at it just by passing it as an argument. Your testing of that pure function has 0 effect on the rest of the program, which makes testing significantly easier.

With the second function, any time you need to test it, you must manually set all the globals the function relies on, which could potentially affect the operation of other functions if they rely on the same globals. This makes testing harder, and for that reason, among others, mutating globals should be avoided.

Comment: But in recursive functions, passing the whole thing may result in many copies of the same vector in the stack. This repetition might be a killer, right?

Comment: @user25004 That depends on the language. If you're passing references to objects, it may make a copy of the reference, but that's dirt cheap. And see my update. I tried to finished the answer before I had to run for the train, so I rushed it. I expanded at the end.

Comment: Also, languages that make extensive use of recursion typically have means of cheap copies, since such languages will also typically be FP and use immutable structures.